# Customize color of selected item in app-drawer, Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

How can you customize the color of the selected tab in the app-drawer?

Also, how to "unbold" the text in the app-drawer and in the paper-tabs.

I'm using polymer 2.0 preview

Comment: The `<app-drawer>` itself doesn't have tabs. Do you mean the "selected tab in `<paper-tabs>`"?

Comment: yes, they both (app-drawer and paper-tabs) make the text bold when you click on it.

Comment: `<app-drawer>` is just a container (see [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-drawer/app-drawer.html)). The `<app-drawer>` itself does not style the selected item, but it could contain another component that automatically styles the selected item (including `<paper-tabs>`), so if we understood the full context of `<app-drawer>`, we could provide more helpful/accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the markup and use different elements if you like. For the standard PSK drawer, these are the styles to change

```
  .drawer-list {
    margin: 0 20px;
  }
  .drawer-list a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--app-secondary-color);
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```